# Codeigniter Undefined variable

Tags: php, codeigniter

### Undefined

Now I want to create update function and I had appeared problem with undefined variable. I am using same method in adding there this working fine. I am newbie in coding maybe there have simple answer but I cannot find.

### Controller

```
$event_title = $this->input->post('title');
            $event_description = $this->input->post('description');
            $event_phone = $this->input->post('phone');
            $event_email = $this->input->post('email');
            $event_keywords = $this->input->post('keywords');
            $date_start = $this->input->post('date_start');
            $time_start = $this->input->post('time_start');
            $date_end = $this->input->post('date_end');
            $time_end = $this->input->post('time_end');

            $start = date_format(date_create( $date_start.' '.$time_start),"Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $end = date_format(date_create( $date_end.' '.$time_end),"Y-m-d H:i:s");




            if(!empty($_FILES['picture']['name']))
            {
                $data['picture'] = $this->validator->upload_image('./uploads/events/main','picture'); 
                $this->validator->resize_image($data['picture'],'./uploads/events/main','event_main_size');
            }

            $event_basic = [
                                'title'         => $event_title, 
                                'main_photo'    => $picture,
                                'description'   => $event_description,
                                'email'         => $event_email,
                                'phone'         => $event_phone,
                                'keywords'      => $event_keywords,
                                'start'         => $start,
                                'end'           => $end, 
                                'created_at'    => date('c')
                           ];

            $this->events_model->update_event_base($event_basic,$event_id);
```

### Model

```
public function update_event_base($event_basic,$event_id){
    return  
    $this->db->where('event_id', $event_id)
             ->update('events', $event_basic);
}
```

### Error

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: picture

Comment: from where `$picture` comes here `'main_photo'    => $picture,` ?

Comment: yes uploaded picture comes from $picture

Comment: I don't see any other variable called $picture only $data['picture'] is above $picture also with `$event_basic = [];` think this should be `$event_basic = array ();`

Comment: you didn't define `$picture` variable in code -@RavshanAbdurasulov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this.It may help you.

```
$picture = $_FILES['picture']['name'];
     $event_basic = [
                                'title'         => $event_title, 
                                'main_photo'    => $picture,
                                'description'   => $event_description,
                                'email'         => $event_email,
                                'phone'         => $event_phone,
                                'keywords'      => $event_keywords,
                                'start'         => $start,
                                'end'           => $end, 
                                'created_at'    => date('c')
                           ];
```

Comment: now that return undifined $data

Comment: you sure I think nothing is changed

Comment: I have defied $picture = $_FILES['picture']['name'] at beginning. Please go through it .

Comment: yes that was answer thank you!

Comment: If the answer was helpful for you please vote for my answer.